# How to tell the Amazon Load Balancer which instance to use depending on the User Agent?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

My application needs to serve files to an external applications that sends requests with an specific User agent. I  need to keep the same domain, and keep the same request URL for both, a normal user en this external app.

I had in mind to keep files on each instances I have, but these are too much files and though about the possibility so save space and allocate them in one instance only. I want to use one single instance to serve this files, but how to tell the Load Balancer that if the visitor has this specific User agent, use the instance with the files on it.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon's ELB does not allow you to set up this sort of routing. If saving space is an issue, consider putting the files on shared storage like Amazon S3 rather than individual instances.